# my php session do not die after configurate new session_save_path

Tags: php, session

I want to manage my sessions in another folder than the defined by default.
So I have this in my code :

```
session_name('domain');
session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'../sessions/');

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',300);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
session_start();
```

The sessions are created by the serveur in the right folder and I connect correctly to the site but the sessions do not die passed the defined maxlifetime, here in the script 300, so 5 minutes.
The sessions are destroyed correctly by session_destroy() but it seems that the server do not destroy them by itself.
Did I miss something ?

I have read most part of the documentation but I can't find the cause.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact that's ok.
If the server do not delete old session files in the new session save folder, that's better cause that forced me to think and finally decide to control the sessions through the script itself.
I define in the script the lifetime of the sessions and if the lifetime is passed, I simply empty the session array and I regenerate the session_id(), deleting automatically the old session_id file (see in php doc, the true parameter in session_regenerate_id() function and I connect again automatically.
I will never have old lost session files in the folder cause the script make the optimum treatment.
:)
Solved